# Getting NullPointerException checking if file exists

Tags: android, file, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to improve my delete button, so if I press the button and the file is not there it should launch a Toast that says there is no file to delete, I tried this:

```
  mBtnBorrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {


                 if(file.exists()){
                     file.getAbsoluteFile().delete();
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File deleted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }else
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no file to delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }


             }
         });
```

my file is declared here:

```
 File file;

 File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                 .getPath());

         if (!path.exists() && !path.mkdirs()) {
             throw new IOException("No se pudo crear el directorio del archivo.");
         }else{

             try {
                 file = File.createTempFile("audio", ".3gp", path);
             } catch (IOException e) {
             }

         }
```

Now the problem is that if I try to delete the file with the if I get a `nullpointerexception`, but if I create first the file, then I delete it successfully and then when I press again the delete button it shows the exception that there is no file, but at the startup of the app if I press the button without creating the file it dosnt check if the file is there to delete.

Comment: what is archivo.getAbsoluteFile().delete();

Comment: @zombie sorry, where it says archivo is file , i forgot to change it.

Comment: try to check in the `onClick` like you did in the second part of your code

Comment: @zombie cant get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you execute the code `file = File.createTempFile("audio", ".3gp", path);`, then `file` will be `null`.  If you're testing the delete button before you ever create a file, this will be the case.  A simple null check is a common way to handle this.

**EDIT:** changed null check to `onClick()`

```
        if(file != null) {
             if(file.exists()){
                 file.getAbsoluteFile().delete();
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File deleted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else
             {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no file to delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        }
```

Another way would be to set a flag indicating whether a file had first been created then check the flag in `onClick()`.

FYI, [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) to reference page)

Comment: The check should be in the onClick method

Comment: hi @Gary99 im getting the problem at the onclick method, its giving a nullpointer exception here    if(file.exists()){ ....

Comment: hi i solved it puting if(file !=null) { in the onclick ! thanks

Comment: My mistake.  Yes, the `onClick()` is where it should be.  I was called for dinner in the middle of answering & hurried my copy & pasting the current code.  I'll modify it.